# How to reduce the execution time of uploading many files to Dropbox in Python?

Tags: dropbox

I have 100 files ( .csv) inside the folder and I want to upload these files to Dropbox. I have successfully done this with the following code, but the problem is that the execution time takes a long time. So my question is: How to reduce the execution time of uploading these files to Dropbox in Python.
With my thanks and appreciation

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('Access token')
filename = (os.listdir('path'))
for fn in filename:
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        dbx.files_upload(f.read(), '/sendTOcloud/' + fn + '.csv', mute=True)
```

Comment: Maybe try doing them in parallel with multiprocessing module.

Comment: I recommend reading the Dropbox [Performance Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/dbx-performance-guide).